# How to filter/subset a data.frame using values from one of its column

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I "truncate" a data.frame based on the values in a single column?  For example, if I have this matrix

```
x <- c(5,1,3,2,4)
y <- c(1,5,3,4,2)
data <- data.frame(x,y)
```

and I want all data for values greater than or equal to x, how would I do that?  I know that I can find the addresses of x-values using

```
addresses <- which(x>=2)
```

but I'm not sure how to use this to make a new matrix.  The following do not work:

```
data2 <- data[x>=2]
data2 <- data[which(x>=2)]
```

If anyone can offer any advice, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're not reading the error messages closely enough. Here, our error message tells you that you have not selected any columns. You've specified the condition for the rows though....

```
> data[which(x>=2)]
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, which(x >= 2)) : undefined columns selected
```

Since you want to return all columns, just put a comma in (indicating that you want all columns returned), and you should be all set.

```
> data[which(x>=2), ] # if x is in your workspace
  x y
1 5 1
3 3 3
4 2 4
5 4 2
> ## with(data, data[x >= 2, ] # if x is not in your workspace
```

---

Here's another point to note: You can make your `data.frame` directly like this:

```
data <- data.frame(x = c(5,1,3,2,4), y = c(1,5,3,4,2))
```

Here's why I suggest this. First, there are no unnecessary objects in your workspace. Second, you aren't fooled into thinking something is working when it isn't. You wrote that:  "*I know that I can find the addresses of x-values using `addresses <- which(x>=2)`*". True, but what you perhaps didn't realize (hence this question) is that you aren't actually accessing the "x" from your `data.frame` but the "x" vector in your workspace.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure what the error meant, but I understand it now that I see your solution.  Many thanks again.

Comment: Not only did we post the same answer in the same time, but I think we also made the same edits in the same time :)

Comment: @user1824929 If Ananda Mahto's answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it with the green mark !

Comment: @user1824929 Worth pointing out that if you follow the extra advice (you should!) the above code won't work because `x` won't be defined outside of your data.frame. You'll need to instead use something like `data[which(data$x >= 2), ]`, or `with(data, data[x >= 2, ]`. This is **a good thing** because it will make sure you don't change either `x` or your data without changing the other, which could otherwise get you into trouble.

Comment: @shujaa, thanks. I had actually meant to edit that in, but forgot because I was answering another question at the same time! Oops.

Answer (score 9):

First, `data` is not a matrix, but a data frame. And, what you are trying to do is to index your data frame by rows. This can be done by specifying a condition in the first part of the `[` operator. Something like this :

```
data2 <- data[data$x>=2,]
```

Note that you have nothing between the comma and the closing bracket, because this is the place for column indexing. And here nothing means "select all columns".